# Client(Android) server(pc) works in eclipse but not in Netbeans

Tags: java, android, eclipse, netbeans, client-server

I created a simple Client server program called DoubleMe. The client (android) sends a number and the server (pc) will double it and return the result to android phone.

Here is the step by step instructions i used to create this

http://www.veereshr.com/Android/AndroidToServlet  .

The problem is that it works well in eclipse java EE ide ie when i click Double me Button on phone ,the result doubles .But the same code does not work on Netbeans 8. When i click on double Me button on android nothing happens.

Could anyone please help me .

Comment: Please be more specific. You are running it on a simulator? Did you check the logcat to see if something is going wrong?

Comment: No i am running it on an android  device which is connected to the same network. The connections are right because i got the result using eclipse and tomcat server. But no result while running the server on net beans tomcat

Comment: Did you know how to use logcat? If not open monitor: android-sdk-folder\tools\monitor.bat. Then click on the tab logcat. It will show the log. You can filter for errors. Probably some exception is being raised.

Comment: No problems found in logcat.. But i found something .After connecting and starting my server(IP :192.168.137.1) using eclipse the address  : http://192.168.137.1:8080/ClientServer/DoubleMeServlet (My servlet address) is accessible in phone browser .But if server started using netbeans ' page not found ' appears.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to the problem. My firewall is blocking any connections from outside apps.  When i turn the firewall off,everything worked fine.